# SQL Server Dynamic Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use a dynamic order by in a stored procedure so I can pass the order I want the data returned into the stored procedure as a parameter. This works fine for VARCHAR fields however if I try to sort an int or datetime field it errors the code I  have is as follows

```
DECLARE @ORDERBY INT
SET @ORDERBY = 1
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TBL_LMS_USERS_RECORDs_LAST_ATTEMPT
ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN s10_record_dow
    --WHEN @OrderBy = 2 THEN pk_big_record_id
    else s10_record_dow
END
```

If I uncomment the second WHEN in the case statement it errors with

> "Error converting data type varchar to bigint."

I can order by this field fine if I dont use the case statement.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TBL_LMS_USERS_RECORDs_LAST_ATTEMPT
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN s10_record_dow ELSE NUll END,  
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 2 THEN pk_big_record_id ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy <> 1 AND  @OrderBy <> 2 THEN s10_record_dow 
         ELSE NULL 
    END
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, out of interest why was it working ok how I had it with VARCHAR but in order to use INT or other data types I have to have it this way?

Comment: All fields in the Case need to evaluate to the same datatype.. But, if all the fields in your list can be converted to a single datatype you should be able to use a single Case statement... if you Cast the data columns to that datatype inside the Case

Answer (score 4):

Why not use ROW_NUMBER()?

```
SELECT TOP 10 
       *,
       CASE @SortBy
         WHEN 'A' THEN ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY s10_record_dow)
         WHEN 'B' THEN ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY pk_id)
       END RowNumber
FROM TBL_LMS_USERS_RECORDs_LAST_ATTEMPT
```

Then the columns you order by can be of any type.

Answer (score 0):

```
order by 
(case when (@orderByAsc = 1) then r.SomeColumn end) asc,
(case when (@orderByAsc = 0) then r.SomeColumn end) desc
```

this is how you get ascening or descening