# How to Sort datetime in ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hi the below query is a prototype of a bigger complex query
The problem is that i should be able sort any column in any order (i.e. ASC and DESC) based on user input.

```
CREATE table #Table1(
Name varchar(10) PRIMARY key,
DOB DateTime,
Rate numeric(10,2)  
)

INSERT INTO #Table1 (Name,DOB,Rate) values ('Name1','2/2/2012',10.23)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (Name,DOB,Rate) values ('Name2','3/2/2012',120.23)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (Name,DOB,Rate) values ('Name3','4/2/2012',110.23)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (Name,DOB,Rate) values ('Name4','5/2/2012',140.23)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (Name,DOB,Rate) values ('Name15','6/2/2012',130.23)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (Name,DOB,Rate) values ('Name6','2/21/2012',1120.23)

Declare @SortColumn varchar(10)
DECLARE @SortExpression varchar (10)

SET @SortColumn = 'DOB'
SET @SortExpression = 'DESC' -- Need to sort in both ASC and DESC

Select 
            Name,
            DOB,
            Rate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'Name' then Name
                         WHEN @SortColumn = 'DOB' THEN DOB
                         WHEN @SortColumn = 'Rate' THEN Rate
                    END  +  @SortExpression 
                ) AS RowNumber  
                FROM 
                #Table1
```

Comment: [See the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1479623/73226). Separate queries will likely have better plans though. BTW `ASC` and `DESC` can not be paremeterised as you are trying and all branches of the `CASE` need to be castable to the same datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` the items in the `CASE` to get it to work:

```
Declare @SortColumn varchar(10)
DECLARE @SortExpression varchar (10)

SET @SortColumn = 'DOB'
SET @SortExpression = 'DESC' -- Need to sort in both ASC and DESC

Select 
   Name,
   DOB,
   Rate,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (ORDER BY 
       CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'Name' then Name
            WHEN @SortColumn = 'DOB' THEN convert(char(10), DOB, 120)
            WHEN @SortColumn = 'Rate' THEN Cast(Rate as varchar(10))
       END  ASC
    ) AS RowNumberASC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY 
       CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'Name' then Name
            WHEN @SortColumn = 'DOB' THEN convert(char(10), DOB, 120)
            WHEN @SortColumn = 'Rate' THEN Cast(Rate as varchar(10))
      END DESC
    ) AS RowNumberDESC
FROM Table1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05127/27)

As @Martin pointed out the `ASC`, `DESC` cannot be parameterized.

Comment: `+@SortExpression` just appends the `ASC` / `DESC` to the string that is sorted. It will still be sorted `ASC`

Comment: @MartinSmith I was not aware of that. Removed from my answer. Thanks

Comment: @PeterLang switched to conversion `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: One way to work around the `ASC`/`DESC` problem could be to always select both as two separate columns and decide later which column to use...

Comment: `+1`. You could even avoid one `SORT` using this little [trick](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05127/29), performance would have to be tested, and readability of query too ;)

Comment: @PeterLang that is a nice little trick, I didn't think of that one. :)

Comment: Yet another trick to put `ASC`/`DESC` back into the query: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05127/32) ;)

Comment: @PeterLang you are just proving to me that I still have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to switch between `ASC` and `DESC` dynamically, you will have to use a dynamic statement.
SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/351e53/1). Be aware of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

```
EXECUTE(' SELECT Name, DOB, Rate,'
      + ' ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ' + @SortColumn + ' ' + @SortExpression
      + ' ) AS RowNumber'
      + ' FROM Table1');
```

If your query is complex, consider putting it into a view and select from that view to allow compile-time checking of that part.

Comment: you won't be able to use dynamic sql in a view though, it would have to be a stored proc.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid there is no way to put 'ASC' /'DESC' in a view.