# dynamic order by conversion error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to do a dynamic order by on pubs database and getting the following error
when I try to use `@sort_order = 2`

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Pavlova' to data type int.

[This is the article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-order-by)

```
SELECT * FROM Paging
WHERE seq > (@page_nbr - 1) * @page_size
  AND seq <= @page_nbr * @page_size
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN @sort_order = 1 THEN ProductID
    WHEN @sort_order = 2 THEN ProductName
    ELSE CategoryID
END
```

Comment: What is the value of the parameter `@sort_order` passed to your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProductID`, `ProductName`, and `CategoryID` are of different types. All cases of CASE need to evaluate to the same type.

Check out this thread for other alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/751659/1373170

Both the accepted answer (multiple case statements) and the `ROW_NUMBER()` approach seem valid.