# SQL Server 2012 - Pagination without Order Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found best approach for pagination in SQL Server 2012 is [OFFSET FETCH Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

```
SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name 
FROM Employees 
ORDER BY First Name OFFSET 10 ROWS;
```

It works fine.

Now in my case, my software generate SQL Server table dynamically and I just know table name.

I don't know columns name in dynamically generated table.

Now in this case how this pagination works ? because I don't know which column should be used with `ORDER BY` clause with OFFSET Fetch clause..

any alternative solution?

Thanks

Comment: Without the `ORDER BY`, there **is no ordering** in your result set, so `OFFSET...FETCH...` is **pointless** .....

Comment: What does this have to do with pagination? All you are asking is how to perform a dynamic order by".

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Dynamic Order By Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751642/sql-server-dynamic-order-by-problem)

Comment: @marc_s.. is there any system column like rowid in oracle that I can use for Order Clause..For every page I want to show 10 records only

Comment: @usr, I check SQL Server Dynamic Order By Problem question but It's answer is not satisfied my need

Comment: @usr, I want to show only 10 records on every page So I cant use TOP because it always fetch from starting..I have to do pagination

Comment: You already have working pagination. What is wrong with it? Just add FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS or so.

Comment: @usr, Please read my question again.. I don't know the column name as my table is generated dynamically . If I want to use OFFSET Fetch clause then I have to use ORDER By CLAUSE..I don't know column name so I can not User Order BY Clase

Comment: What did you not understand about marcs statement that pagination without ordering does not make sense? How, in your mind, are you going to specify what column to sort by without an order by?

Comment: @usr, If its not possible then what is alternative.. That is why I have asked question here to find alternative solution

Comment: @Tanner Thanks for you suggestion but It will be great If I can fetch data in same order as they are inserted

Comment: The alternative is to use a dynamic order by.

Comment: @usr, please check answers in dynamic order by post. They have use TOP in query and I can not use TOP because it always show data from top. I need to fetch data 10 by 10.. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere

Comment: @tanner, I think you are right, I don't have primarykey or ID column but I can add and then I can use with Order BY.. Thanks It will work

Comment: If you don't want to use TOP then simply don't. The dynamic ORDER BY is the key point here. The solution will not be served to you on a silver plate. *Minimal* thinking is required here.

Comment: @RonakShah the PK trick will only work if you always want to order by the same column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66048/discussion-between-ronak-shah-and-usr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by column index if that helps:

```
SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name 
FROM Employees 
ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 10 ROWS;
```

This will order by the first column. If the ordering column is stored on the UI (controlled by users), then you need to store the column index on the UI and pass that to SQL Server to use in the ordering.

If you simply want to order by the order the records are added to the table, you will need a primary key, identity column. Make sure that is the first column on the table and use `ORDER BY 1`.

Comment: And what if your table Joins to others?

Comment: @schmoopy I don't understand, if you have a new question, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tanner mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248551/3367974), in order to use his answer you have to put identity column as the first column of your query, if you can do that, use his answer, but if you can not, use `(SELECT NULL)` instead of `1`, e.g:

```
SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name 
FROM Employees 
ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) OFFSET 10 ROWS;
```